# How do I get the IDs of connected peers?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I managed to get the number of peers connected in my console log by having the console print out "You are peer number n" for each new connected peer.
Is there a way of adding the id of each connected peer too?
I'm relatively new with socket.io and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

This is my server.js file:

```
var app = require("express")();
var express = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var p2pserver = require("socket.io-p2p-server").Server;
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
io.use(p2pserver);

var peerNum = 0;

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  console.log("Peer " + peerNum + " connected");
  io.emit("peer-num", peerNum);
  peerNum++;

  ss(socket).on("file", function(stream, data) {

    var filename = path.basename(data.name);

    var parts = [];

    stream.on("data", function(data) {
      parts.push(data);
    });

    stream.on("end", function() {
      socket.broadcast.emit("file", parts);
    });

  });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Listening on 8080")
});
```

This is my client.js file:

```
// Browserified
var P2P = require("socket.io-p2p");
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var socket = io();
var opts = {autoUpgrade: true, peerOpts: {numClients: 10}};
var p2p = new P2P(socket, opts);
var $ = require("jquery");

p2p.on("peer-num", function(num) {
  console.log("You are peer number " + num);
  $(".peerNum").html( "Number " + num );
});

p2p.on("file", function(stream) {
  console.log(stream);

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(stream));
  document.getElementById("receivedImages").appendChild(img);
});

$(function() {
  $("#file").change(function(e) {
    ss.forceBase64 = true;
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var stream = ss.createStream();

    ss(socket).emit("file", stream, {size: file.size,name:file.name});
    var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
    var size = 0;
    blobStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
      size += chunk.length;
      console.log(Math.floor(size / file.size * 100) + "%");
    });
    blobStream.pipe(stream);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by id is the internal id that socket.io assigns to a connection (on the server), then you can access that with `socket.id`.  So, if you want to just use `socket.id` instead of your `peerNum`, variable, then you would change this:

```
io.emit("peer-num", peerNum);
```

to this:

```
io.emit("peer-num", socket.id);
```

The `socket.id` value is used only on the server.  It is not meant to be a human readable moniker (it contains randomly generated characters), but it can be used to reference any given connection.  Since its a string, it can be easily sent to other clients who can then use it when sending messages back to the server to reference particular client connections.